# Windows Forms how to find out if selectedindex was changed by user or by code

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I have a combobox in a Windows Forms project with an event attached to the selectedindex changed event.   The event is getting triggered when the selectedindex is changed both from code and from user input.  How do you detect if the selectedindex is getting changed due to user input?

Comment: Can you explain why you want to do this? It seems like a pretty severe violation of encapsulation to make a method act differently depending on what called it.

Comment: I want to know when the user changed a value and not just when the value is initially set.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Can you use the [SelectionChangeCommitted](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.combobox.selectionchangecommitted.aspx) event instead?

> SelectionChangeCommitted is raised only when the **user** changes the combo box selection

EDIT: The SelectionChangeCommitted event has a major failing: if you use F4 to drop down the list then mouse over your selection and use the Tab key to go to the next control, it does not fire.

There's a [closed and deleted] bug on [Connect](http://web.archive.org/web/20110315220946/http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/115189/selectionchangecommitted-event-sometimes-not-raised-by-combobox) about it, which suggests using the `DropDownClosed` event as well to catch this edge case.

Comment: +1 I never know such an event, nice! I always use a flag to check if it's changed by users or programmatically.

Comment: I still have a problem determining whether `SelectionChangeCommitted` was caused by up down arrow, spacebar or mouse click. I can handle those events and use `Boolean` flags, but that seems messy.

Comment: Seemed to be very problematic in my case.  I will rely on flags.  Thanks for the info though

Comment: @JSON there's really no need to thank me, especially after all this time. But thank you.

Comment: @stuartd It's nice to see you still check in from time to time :D

Answer (score 7):

I've gotten stuck in situations before where a UI change propagates to the Model, then the Model change propagates back to the UI and it creates an endless cycle.  Are you dealing with something like that?

If so, one way out is to only update the UI from the model only if they differ.  That is:

```
if (comboBox.SelectedItem != newValue)
    comboBox.SelectedItem = newValue;
```

If that doesn't get you what you want, another option is to temporarily remove the event handler:

```
comboBox.SelectedIndexChanged -= this.comboBox_SelectedIndexChanged;
comboBox.SelectedIndex = newIndex;
comboBox.SelectedIndexChanged += this.comboBox_SelectedIndexChanged;
```

or, instruct the handler to ignore this event:

```
ignoreComboBoxEvents = true;
comboBox.SelectedIndex = newIndex;
ignoreComboBoxEvents = false;
...
public void comboBox_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (ignoreComboBoxEvents)
        return;
    ...
}
```

Comment: +1 nice and flexible solution with the ignore-flag. Good workaround if you have a lot of values updated at the same time

Comment: I like the second workaround.  Seems to work nicely, and no need for flags!

Answer (score 0):

Your event handler is only called after user input, and not after code changing the index. 
Either handle that case there, or set a boolean flag there saying it was user input so that another part of the code can see that the last index change was due to user input.

Answer (score 0):

You can set a boolean flag whenever the selectedindex is changed by the code, and the handler can abort (resetting the flag) whenever that flag is set.